# How to rotate an image along a path in a svg animation?

Tags: html, animation, svg, path

I have an image that animates along a path that curbs.

I would like it so that the image auto rotates to the curb but stay on top of the path.

Any ideas?

[image]

```html
<svg id="da" width="800" height="600" viewBox="0 0 800 600">
    <path id="motionPath" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10"
        d="M 814.00,140.00
           C 814.00,140.00 664.00,112.50 632.50,106.50
             601.50,102.50 534.00,95.50 509.00,94.50
             484.00,93.50 417.00,92.00 374.00,94.00
             334.00,98.00 298.00,96.00 242.00,104.00
             186.00,112.00 167.00,118.00 150.00,122.00
             134.48,127.70 90.95,139.46 99.00,156.50
             109.00,173.50 166.00,210.00 201.00,232.00
             236.00,254.00 719.50,587.00 757.50,608.00"/>

    <filter id="horse_image" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
        <feImage xlink:href="https://massinflux.com/1.png"/>
    </filter>
    <circle id="circle" filter="url(#horse_image)" cx="0" cy="0" r="20"/>

    <animateMotion
            rotate="auto-reverse"
            xlink:href="#circle"
            dur="10s"
            begin="0s"
            fill="freeze"
            repeatCount="indefinite">
        <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath"/>
    </animateMotion>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to split your path into two parts (ie. one for the top part, and one for the second part after the turn) to make it stay on top when it folds under.

Or you could turn off auto rotation completely, so it stays upright (see below).

```html
<svg id="da" width="800" height="600" viewBox="0 0 800 600">
    <path id="motionPath" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10"
        d="M 814.00,140.00
           C 814.00,140.00 664.00,112.50 632.50,106.50
             601.50,102.50 534.00,95.50 509.00,94.50
             484.00,93.50 417.00,92.00 374.00,94.00
             334.00,98.00 298.00,96.00 242.00,104.00
             186.00,112.00 167.00,118.00 150.00,122.00
             134.48,127.70 90.95,139.46 99.00,156.50
             109.00,173.50 166.00,210.00 201.00,232.00
             236.00,254.00 719.50,587.00 757.50,608.00"/>

    <filter id="horse_image" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
        <feImage xlink:href="https://massinflux.com/1.png"/>
    </filter>
    <circle id="circle" filter="url(#horse_image)" cx="0" cy="0" r="20"/>

    <animateMotion
            rotate="0"
            xlink:href="#circle"
            dur="10s"
            begin="0s"
            fill="freeze"
            repeatCount="indefinite">
        <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath"/>
    </animateMotion>
</svg>
```